# if else condition in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I have a problem with my project ,

I want to read my data from excel and insert to database , 
but before it  ,

but i some condition , i input wrong datetime format in my excel , so it make an error in my program ,
so i think i want to validate my data before process it to database ,

this is my code ,

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            if (ddlTest.SelectedValue.Length != 0)
            {
                string filename = "Schedule" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd_dd_MMMM_yyyy") + ".xls";
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(temp_file + filename);
                string tempfile = temp_file + filename;
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo(tempfile); //+ FileUpload1.FileName);
                using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
                {
                    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                    int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                    int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                    table.Columns.Add("Emp_NIK", typeof(string));
                    table.Columns.Add("ID_Shift", typeof(string));
                    table.Columns.Add("Schedule_Date", typeof(DateTime));
                    for (int i = 1; i < rowCount; i++)
                    {
                       try
                        {

                            DateTime d;
                            bool validate = DateTime.TryParseExact(
                            worksheet.Cells[i + 1, 3].Value.ToString(),
                            "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss",
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                            DateTimeStyles.None,
                            out d);
                            TableRow row = new TableRow();
                            TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
                            if (validate == true)
                            {
                                string labelmonth = ddlTest.SelectedValue.ToString();
                                string shift = worksheet.Cells[i + 1, 2].Value.ToString();
                                string employee_id = worksheet.Cells[i + 1, 1].Value.ToString();
                                DateTime schedule_date = DateTime.Parse(worksheet.Cells[i + 1, 3].Value.ToString());
                                string user = Session["LogedUserID"].ToString();
                                bool validatemonth = ddlTest.SelectedValue.ToString() == DateTime.Parse(worksheet.Cells[i + 1, 3].Value.ToString()).ToString("MM");
                                if (validatemonth == false)
                                {
                                    cell1.Text = worksheet.Cells[i + 1, 1].Value.ToString() + "  " + worksheet.Cells[i + 1, 2].Value.ToString() + " " + worksheet.Cells[i + 1, 3].Value.ToString() + " Baris ke " + i + " Bulan Tidak Sesuai";
                                    row.Cells.Add(cell1);
                                    mytable.Rows.Add(row);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    schedule.InsertData(employee_id, shift, schedule_date, user);
                                }

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                cell1.Text = worksheet.Cells[i + 1, 1].Value.ToString() + "  " + worksheet.Cells[i + 1, 2].Value.ToString() + " " + worksheet.Cells[i + 1, 3].Value.ToString() + " Baris ke " + i + "Format Tanggal salah";
                                row.Cells.Add(cell1);
                                mytable.Rows.Add(row);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception err)
                        {
                            Response.Write("<script>window.alert('File Excel Kosong')</script>");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script>window.alert('Pilih Bulan Terlebih dahulu')</script>");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script>window.alert('File Belum Di Upload')</script>");
        }
```

for example ,i have 5 row data in my excel ,
1 row is invalid and 4 row is valid ,
I wish when i row is invalid ,another 4 row is failed to inserted to database ,
but current condition is when a row is invalid ,another row still inserted to database

How can i solve this?

Comment: You can use `Transaction` to do: `Submit()` if succeed and `Rollback()` if anything goes wrong.

Comment: can you tell me ,how to implement it technically?

Comment: I need the codes of `schedule.InsertData()`. And you may do that as an option: 1. initial an SqlTransaction instance e.g.: `transaction` first; then 2, pass `transaction` to `schedule.InsertData()`; 3, do `transaction.Commit();` if all rows are valid, otherwise, call `transaction.Rollback()';

Comment: public void InsertData(string sEmpNIK, string sIDShift, DateTime dScheduleDate,string sUser)
        { conn = objDBConnector.GetConn();
            cmd = objDBConnector.GetCommand();
            SqlDataReader rdr = null;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "insertdata";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emp_NIK", sEmpNIK);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_Shift", sIDShift);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Schedule_Date", dScheduleDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", sUser);
        }

Comment: this the codes you need , stackoverflow have limited comment character ,
i am sorry if my writing looks not tidy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my comments above. please check the following code as reference:

```
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            if (ddlTest.SelectedValue.Length != 0)
            {
                string filename = "Schedule" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd_dd_MMMM_yyyy") + ".xls";
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(temp_file + filename);
                string tempfile = temp_file + filename;
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo(tempfile); //+ FileUpload1.FileName);
                using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
                {
    SqlTransaction transaction = objDBConnector.GetConn().BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");
                    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                    int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                    int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                    table.Columns.Add("Emp_NIK", typeof(string));
                    table.Columns.Add("ID_Shift", typeof(string));
                    table.Columns.Add("Schedule_Date", typeof(DateTime));
                    for (int i = 1; i < rowCount; i++)
                    {
                       try
                        {

                            DateTime d;
                            bool validate = DateTime.TryParseExact(
                            worksheet.Cells[i + 1, 3].Value.ToString(),
                            "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss",
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                            DateTimeStyles.None,
                            out d);
                            TableRow row = new TableRow();
                            TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
                            if (validate == true)
                            {
                                string labelmonth = ddlTest.SelectedValue.ToString();
                                string shift = worksheet.Cells[i + 1, 2].Value.ToString();
                                string employee_id = worksheet.Cells[i + 1, 1].Value.ToString();
                                DateTime schedule_date = DateTime.Parse(worksheet.Cells[i + 1, 3].Value.ToString());
                                string user = Session["LogedUserID"].ToString();
                                bool validatemonth = ddlTest.SelectedValue.ToString() == DateTime.Parse(worksheet.Cells[i + 1, 3].Value.ToString()).ToString("MM");
                                if (validatemonth == false)
                                {
                                    cell1.Text = worksheet.Cells[i + 1, 1].Value.ToString() + "  " + worksheet.Cells[i + 1, 2].Value.ToString() + " " + worksheet.Cells[i + 1, 3].Value.ToString() + " Baris ke " + i + " Bulan Tidak Sesuai";
                                    row.Cells.Add(cell1);
                                    mytable.Rows.Add(row);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    schedule.InsertData(transaction, employee_id, shift, schedule_date, user);
                                }

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                cell1.Text = worksheet.Cells[i + 1, 1].Value.ToString() + "  " + worksheet.Cells[i + 1, 2].Value.ToString() + " " + worksheet.Cells[i + 1, 3].Value.ToString() + " Baris ke " + i + "Format Tanggal salah";
                                row.Cells.Add(cell1);
                                mytable.Rows.Add(row);
                            }

if(mytable.Rows != null && mytable.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    transaction.Rollback();
}
else
{
    transaction.Commit();
}
                        }
                        catch (Exception err)
                        {
transaction.Rollback();
                            Response.Write("<script>window.alert('File Excel Kosong')</script>");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script>window.alert('Pilih Bulan Terlebih dahulu')</script>");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script>window.alert('File Belum Di Upload')</script>");
        }
```

Comment: how about code in  schedule.insertdata() ,do i need make any changes?

Comment: No changes for now.